# JS: variables logs undefined, despite being defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

The following code snippet logs undefined. Could someone please explain why?

```js
var x = 100;

function test() {
  if (false) {
    var x = 199;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
test();
```

Comment: The line that assigns to `x` inside `test` never runs...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting ... `var` declarations are function scoped, not block scoped.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's the whole point of the question. Despite being never run, the declaration is hoisted, creating a function scoped variable `x` that is never assigned a value.